# How to create widget has button close and open in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have flutter web application and i went to add Call help chat as Align() widget in bottom right

how can add this with button X to close and button O to open chat widget?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understood correctly, but are you asking that how to make the widget clickable ? if yes, wrap it with inkwell or gesture detector.

Else, if you mean how make a button take action on another widgets.. you need to implement the methods for the other widget and call them from Button's onPressed argument with SetState() => to re-render the UI.

for example:

```
InkWell( 
       onPressed: setState((){
            popUpChatWindow(); // for example
       }
       );
```